# Search string containing spaces in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have implemented a filter/search box on a table to filter out results based on the string input. But when I type a string that contains a space , (for example: John Doe), the filter component does not output the result with respect to "John Doe".

---

To be more clear, if there are 3 entries, 1. John, 2. John Doe, 3. John Doe Smith,

When the input for the search box is "John", all 3 entries are displayed. When the input is "John Doe" , the result still shows all 3 entries instead of just 2.

I would like to know why the space is not taken into consideration. When implemented in AngularJS 1.x, there is no problem. But unable to get it to work in Angular2. Is there any specific condition I need to add on the input string?

```
    onKeyUp()
    {
       if(this.value.length >= 3)
           this.onkeyup.emit(this.value);
    }
```

I do this so that the search query gives results only after 3 characters are inputted. But if I continue the search string which includes spaces, the results do not get updated.

Also when I backspace a character, the search results again do not get updated.

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you tried. Also a Plunker that allows to reproduce would be very helpful.

Comment: take the searched value in variable and try with javascript substr() Function